# How can I use UpdateData func in controlling function (UINT) in MFC App?

Tags: c++, multithreading, user-interface, mfc, static-methods

I'm creating a multi-threading program with `MFC` using controlling function is `UINT`.
Now I want to update GUI using `UpdateData(FALSE)`, but visual studio 2022 say that

```
- a nonstatic member reference must be relative to a specific object
- CWnd::UpdateData': illegal call of non-static member function
```

Here is my `UINT` code:

```
UINT MyThreadProc(LPVOID Param) {
CFolderPickerDialog m_dlg;
   m_dlg.m_ofn.lpstrTitle = _T("Select Folder To Scan");
   m_dlg.m_ofn.lpstrInitialDir = _T("C:\\");
   if (m_dlg.DoModal() == IDOK) {
       m_Path = m_dlg.GetPathName();   
       m_Path += _T("\\");
       CWnd::UpdateData(FALSE);
   }
}

void CMultithreadDlg::OnBnClickedButtonBrowse(){
   AfxBeginThread(MyThreadProc,this);
   UpdateData(FALSE);
   GetDlgItem(IDC_BUTTON_Browse)->EnableWindow(FALSE);
   GetDlgItem(IDC_EDIT_PATH)->EnableWindow(FALSE);
}
```

How can I fix this, thanks

Comment: Do you expect that the folder picker dialog runs in its own thread while the rest of the program continues to run? This cannot be implemented in a simplistic "just run it in a different thread" way. Things are waaaay more complicated.

Comment: In addition to the threading problem, you have to call `UpdateData` for a *specific* window, not for all `CWnd`s in general.

Comment: There doesn't appear to be any reason to offload the `CFolderPickerDialog` UI onto a separate thread. Just move that code into your button click handler, and things will just work. Modal dialogs spin up a nested message loop, so the button click handler won't block indefinitely.

Answer (score 2):

Let's consider that `CFolderPickerDialog` was just an example, and get back to the core of the question.

Your compiler told you that the way you call `UpdateData()`

```
CWnd::UpdateData(FALSE);
```

is specifying a call to a static function `UpdateData()` of the class `CWnd`, and that doesn't exists.

You need to call that function on a specific instance of `CWnd`. Luckily - you have it! You pass your `this` pointer to that thread function:

```
AfxBeginThread(MyThreadProc,this);
```

So inside that function you can safely cast `LPVOID Param` (that you are not using currently) to a pointer to `CWnd` or `CMultithreadDlg`. Then you will be able to call any non-static functions via that pointer.

Comment: This allows the compiler to compile buggy code. Before, things were fine: The code didn't compile, and noone got hurt. Now, though, things have changed. One can now execute code that's intended to run on multiple threads, but doesn't do anything to make sure that it can. The behavior is undefined, in terms of the programming language, and a crash or vulnerability waiting to happen in reality. *"you can safely cast `LPVOID Param`"* - Safely? No. This is your entry ticket into UB land.